# Protobuf - Missing toByteArray()?

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I probably just messed up something in my proto file but I can't seem to call the toByteArray function.

Using Java and the proto file was compiled with protoc.

What I'm calling...

```
BaseMessage.builder = baseMessage = BaseMessage.newBuilder();
Acknowledgement.builder = acknowledgeMessage = Acknowledgement.newBuilder();

acknowledgeMessage.setOk(true);

baseMessage.setAcknowledgement(acknowledgeMessage);
baseMessage.build();

byte[] send = baseMessage.toByteArray();
```

And BaseMessage is declared as...

```
public static final class BaseMessage   
       extends com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessage   
       implements BaseMessageOrBuilder {
```

Maybe I'm missing somthing...

BaseMessage is extending [GeneratedMessage](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage#toByteArray) which inherits toByteArray() from [AbstractMessageLite](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/AbstractMessageLite#toByteArray()) in which toByteArray is public... So I should be able to use it?

Comment: Is it in a superclass?

Comment: public static final class BaseMessage extends com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessage implements BaseMessageOrBuilder {  


I mean GeneratedMessage has toByteArray on it so... Shouldn't this just work? Or am I missing somthing simple?

Comment: If `GeneratedMessage` has `toByteArray`, then `BaseMessage` also has `toByteArray`.  Of course, if it's `private` or `protected` you won't be able to use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you are, you probably meant:

```
baseMessage.build().toByteArray()
```

Comment: This seems to work. I thought I had to be missing something simple like that.