# Google protobuf generated Java does not support toByteArray

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I have used `protoc` to generate Java source from

https://github.com/mapbox/vector-tile-spec/blob/master/2.1/vector_tile.proto

[The protobuf documentation](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/javatutorial#parsing-and-serialization) suggests that the resulting class should support a `toByteArray` method. It doesn't. (As well as trying to call it, I have searched the generated file `VectorTile.java` and there is no `toByteArray` code in there.)

NB. this is not a duplicate of [Protobuf - Missing toByteArray()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25234611/protobuf-missing-tobytearray) -- the error there is using a Builder where a Message is intended. I'm not doing that.

I'd be grateful for any insights.

Comment: I just tried it with protocol buffers 3 and I do see the method.

Comment: Ah, perhaps the problem is that I was using proto2.

Answer (score 1):

The `toByteArray()` method is implemented in `AbstractMessageLite`, which the generated code inherits. There isn't a declaration of `toByteArray()` in the generated code because it is inherited. Calling `message.toByteArray()` will work fine -- if it isn't working for you, please show your code and the error message produced.