# Protobuf - toByteArray method not there on my class

Tags: protocol-buffers

First of all, yes, I have read this thread, [Protobuf - Missing toByteArray()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25234611/protobuf-missing-tobytearray), that didn't solve my issue.

I installed protobuf following this exact steps described here: https://gist.github.com/sofyanhadia/37787e5ed098c97919b8c593f0ec44d8.

My proto file is very simple:

```
syntax = "proto3";
package com.mypackage.protobuf;

message MensajeSMS {
  string telefono = 1;
  string mensaje = 2;
}
```

I go to my proto route and protocompile it using:

```
protoc --java_out=/home/myhome/myproject/myprotoclass/ MensajeSMS.proto
```

The class is indeed created, it has several methods, but not all specified here:  https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/MessageLite

Like some guy says it should be:

"The toByteArray() method is certainly there as it's defined in the Message interface for all message types:
https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/MessageLite.html"

Said here:
https://github.com/google/protobuf/issues/2643

So, I'm clearly doing something wrong. How can I make protoc to generate my class with toByteArray method?

**EDIT**

Here's the code:

```
MensajeSMS xxx = MensajeSMS.newBuilder()
                            .setTelefono(mensajeSMS.getTelefono())
                            .setMensaje(mensajeSMS.getMensaje())
                            .build();

byte[] mybyte = xxx.toByteArray(); //Here I get cannot resolve method
```

Comment: Could you add the code where you are using the proto, and the error message that you get?

Comment: Edited to add code where I get the error. @Luc

Answer (score 1):

So, I found the answer, and it wasn't code related. More data was indeed needed, I thought that everything else I was doing wasn't relevant.

The problem is I was compiling my project into a jar and using it in another project, BUT I was compiling using

```
./gradlew build
```

and not

```
./gradlew buidl fatJar
```

which is what I need to include all dependencies in my jar.

I just hope this helps someone elses. My bad.